# Firebase function fetch json response

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-cloud-functions

currently I have an ionic app that has a function that fetches responses and maps them through an external API, how can I set this up as a firebase function instead and have it inside my provider that includes the current function? I already have Firebase being used for login.

This is one of the functions I would like to move into a firebase function:

```js
grabRAW(email): Observable<any> {
    return this.grabID(email)
      .switchMap(data => {
        this.idList = data.data;
        let id = this.idList[0].id;

        // Now send the second http request
        return this.http.get(((this.url1.concat(id))).concat(this.url2))
          .map((res: Response) => res.json())
          //.do((res:Response) => console.log(res))
      });
  }
```

GrabID function being used:

```js
grabID(email): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url.concat(email))
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      //.do((res:Response) => console.log(res))
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-rxjs

Comment: I'm not really a professional so if you could point me to a simple tutorial or tell me how to implement this in my code/firebase that would be great.

Comment: Just walk through the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) you will know how to do this